# Wordpress permalink not working on Ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to use post name permalink for my wordpress theme. Although it works on my local Mac desktop, when I transfer the codes to Ubuntu server, the links stop working anymore. But the default links format still works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have full access on the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you includet you .htaccess file?

MacOS hides "dot" files by default, just like Windows. You can use a Terminal command to reveal the hidden files in OS X by making a change to the default behavior of Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Alternatively, you can create an empty .htaccess file on your server, set proper file rights and just click 'save' on the permalink settings page in your dashboard again. Wordpress will happily recreate the file content, according to your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out the file path in my .htaccess file was incorrect. Thanks everyone.